# Python Tkinter: Listbox mouse enter event for a specific entry

Tags: python, tkinter, listbox, mouseover

It is possible to create events for when the mouse pointer enters/leaves the entire Listbox using `<Enter>`/`<Leave>`. How can I track when the mouse enters or leaves a **specific entry** (row) in the Listbox?

I want to color in different color the background of the entry over which the mouse pointer is currently located.

Answer (score 4):

Here's an (half) attempt to do what you want by binding to the `<Motion>` event instead of the pair `<Enter>` and `<Leave>`. This because `<Enter>` is raised only when we enter the `Listbox` from outside it, but once we are inside a `Listbox` with the mouse, no other `<Enter>` event will be raised, and we cannot keep track of which item the mouse is above.

Calling a function every time the mouse moves might result in an overload of work, so I don't think this feature is worthing doing it (in this way).

The program does not still work perfectly, and I still have to understand why: basically, sometimes the item's background and font color are not changed properly, there's some kind of delay or something.

```
from tkinter import *


class CustomListBox(Listbox):

    def __init__(self, master=None, *args, **kwargs):
        Listbox.__init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs)

        self.bg = "white"
        self.fg = "black"
        self.h_bg = "#eee8aa"
        self.h_fg = "blue"

        self.current = -1  # current highlighted item

        self.fill()

        self.bind("<Motion>", self.on_motion)
        self.bind("<Leave>", self.on_leave)

    def fill(self, number=15):
        """Fills the listbox with some numbers"""
        for i in range(number):
            self.insert(END, i)
            self.itemconfig(i, {"bg": self.bg})
            self.itemconfig(i, {"fg": self.fg})

    def reset_colors(self):
        """Resets the colors of the items"""
        for item in self.get(0, END):
            self.itemconfig(item, {"bg": self.bg})
            self.itemconfig(item, {"fg": self.fg})

    def set_highlighted_item(self, index):
        """Set the item at index with the highlighted colors"""
        self.itemconfig(index, {"bg": self.h_bg})
        self.itemconfig(index, {"fg": self.h_fg})    

    def on_motion(self, event):
        """Calls everytime there's a motion of the mouse"""
        print(self.current)
        index = self.index("@%s,%s" % (event.x, event.y))
        if self.current != -1 and self.current != index:
            self.reset_colors()
            self.set_highlighted_item(index)
        elif self.current == -1:
            self.set_highlighted_item(index)
        self.current = index

    def on_leave(self, event):
        self.reset_colors()
        self.current = -1


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tk()
    CustomListBox(root).pack()
    root.mainloop()
```

Note that I have used `from tkinter import *` for typing faster, but I recommend you to use `import tkinter as tk`.

Answer (score 3):

No, you cannot track when it enters/leaves a specific row. However, you can track when it enters/leaves the widget, and you can compute which item the mouse is over by using the `index` method of the listbox. If you give an index of the form "@x,y", it will return the numerical index.

For example:

```
self.listbox.bind("<Enter>", self.on_enter)
...
def on_enter(self, event):
    index = self.listbox.index("@%s,%s" % (event.x, event.y))
    ...
```